# How can I make a combination array which contains maximum length?

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have these three arrays:

```
$arr1 = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
$arr2 = ['three', 'four'];
$arr3 = ['two', 'five', 'six', 'seven'];
```

And this is expected result:

```
/* Array
   (
       [0] => one
       [1] => two
       [3] => three
       [4] => four
       [5] => five
       [6] => six
       [7] => seven
   )
```

---

[Here](https://3v4l.org/fdvtf) is my solution which doesn't work as expected:

```
print_r( array_unique( $arr1 + $arr2 + $arr3) );
/* Array
   (
       [0] => one
       [1] => two
       [2] => three
       [3] => seven
   )
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this:

```
array_unique(array_merge($arr1,$arr2,$arr3), SORT_REGULAR);
```

this will merge the arrays into one, then removes all duplicates

Tested [Here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/223f20bd509f1550af717fe7340403674d4a74a9)

It outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
    [2] => three
    [4] => four
    [6] => five
    [7] => six
    [8] => seven
)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this will work just fine

```
$arr1 = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
$arr2 = ['three', 'four'];
$arr3 = ['two', 'five', 'six', 'seven'];
$n_array = array_values(array_unique(array_merge($arr1 , $arr2 , $arr3)));
echo "<pre>";print_r($n_array);echo "</pre>";die;
```

Output is

```
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
    [2] => three
    [3] => four
    [4] => five
    [5] => six
    [6] => seven
)
```

Comment: The nicest answer, you also cared about keys as well.

Comment: Thanks @ShaunakShukla

Answer (score 1):

> **Just Do That.. use `array_uniqe`**
>
> Demo: https://eval.in/827705

```
<?php

    $arr1 = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
    $arr2 = ['three', 'four'];
    $arr3 = ['two', 'five', 'six', 'seven'];
    
    
    print_r ($difference = array_unique(array_merge($arr1, $arr2,$arr3)));
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use array_merge then, array_unique

```
$arr1 = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
$arr2 = ['three', 'four'];
$arr3 = ['two', 'five', 'six', 'seven'];

print_r(array_unique (array_merge($arr1,$arr2,$arr3)));
```

Result

```
Array ( [0] => one [1] => two [2] => three [4] => four [6] => five [7] => six [8] => seven )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $arr1 = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
    $arr2 = ['three', 'four'];
    $arr3 = ['two', 'five', 'six', 'seven'];
    $merge_arr = array_merge($arr1,$arr2,$arr3);
    $unique_arr = array_unique($merge_arr);
    echo '<pre>';
        print_r($unique_arr);
    echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
    [2] => three
    [4] => four
    [6] => five
    [7] => six
    [8] => seven
)
```